# Create docker image without source image (OS)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can we create a docker image using docker file with out source image (OS) i.e

```
FROM rhel
```

We don't want base image(centos or rhel) in all our application docker images. we want to separate base image(centos or rhel) and application images and link them during run time. Is it possible?

When I am building docker image **without** `FROM centos` or `rhel`, docker complains: "provide source image before commit"

My docker file looks like this:

```
MAINTAINER abc

RUN mkdir /opt/cassandra

RUN cd /opt/cassandra

RUN wget http://www.interior-dsgn.com/apache/cassandra/2.1.2/apache-cassandra-2.1.2-bin.tar.gz

RUN tar xvzf apache-cassandra-2.1.2-bin.tar.gz

RUN cd apache-cassandra-2.1.2-bin
```

Comment: Docker doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You said "*we want to separate base image(centos or rhel) and application images and link them during run time.*" That is essentially what `FROM rhel` does, thanks to the layered file systems used by Docker.

That is, the `FROM` image does not become part of your image -- it remains in a separate layer. Your new image points to that `rhel` (or other `FROM`'d base layer) and then adds itself on top of it at runtime.

So go ahead and use `FROM` -- you'll get the behavior you wanted.

For those that find this question looking for a way to build their own base image (so you don't have to use anything as a base), you can use `FROM scratch` and you should read about [Creating a base image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/).

And, to be completely pedantic, the reason why Docker needs a `FROM` and a base including a Linux distribution's root file system is that without a root file system, there is nothing. You can't even `RUN mkdir /opt/cassandra` because `mkdir` is a program provided by the root file system.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried everything and realized you need root file system. Just needed another opinion to conclude.