# Should docker container have a OS distro?

Tags: java, docker

I am new to docker and following many tutorials. I came to know that we can include any thing (db, server etc) in docker container. However, I saw in many tutorials that docker image files have a "`FROM` some OS distro" (I know that this distro is not a complete OS, but provides the utilities, processes of the distro).  My question is that:

should always a container have a OS distro ?

If yes, why? (Can't the rest of components (For instance: java vm) run on the kernel ?),

If no: what are the ramifications? Or what could be the best practice in general ?
(I am from Java background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create docker image without source image (OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100576/create-docker-image-without-source-image-os)

Answer (score 1):

Every docker image you define must have a FROM clause becuase it needs to be based on another image. You can create your own base image but imo you should not need it. An image is nothing more than a collection of binaries you can use in your container created from your image. There are lots of images available on docker hub, whereby best pratice is to keep the images as small as possible. Therefore I would recommend base images based on alpine.

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

If you really need an own base image take a look here

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

and also on the linked stackoverflow article of the comment.

Processes of docker containers always use the kernel of the docker host, therefore the docker images need to be compatible with the kernel of the host running the containers. A docker conttainer is nothing more than an isolated process running on the host, there is no special runtime. If a java process is running in a container its actually running on the host and you can see it when you list the host processes on the docker host.

Comment: I think the question is "what would happen if i try to put java binaries and run them on image with `FROM scratch`"

Comment: Nothing should happen, because scratch is an explicitly empty image, just telling the docker engine that the next commad in the Dockerfile produces the first layer of the image. Java depends on linux binaries for running the Java JVM as well as the runtime itself, so scratch image is useless for running java applications.

Comment: _"Every docker image you define must have a FROM clause"_ Really?! How do you think those OS images are defined? There must be a starting point somewhere, which implies that having a `FROM` is not required. I agree though, that using `FROM` would mean you have to do all the bootstrapping yourself.

Comment: If you build your own base image an you have no FROM directive in your Dockerfile then its the same as you would have 'FROM scratch'  isn't it? Ok, you have no FROM directive in the Dockerfile, but thats seems just to be syntatic sugar.