# does docker always need an operating system as base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have heard that docker doesn't need a separate os in linux, because it shares with the host os, but in hyper-v Windows it can run Windows OS because it can hyper a linux virtual machine so run linux software on it.

But, I get confused about the `FROM` stage in the dockerfile, all guides said like this:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
cp . /usr/local/bin
RUN make
CMD /usr/local/bin/youapp
```

I can understand this step, first you need an OS, then you deploy your application; finally you run your app or whatever.

But what does the FROM stage really mean?

Does it always need an OS? Does nginx docker image have an os in it?

If i want to build my own app, I write it, I compile it, I run it; but does my own app need an OS?  If not, what should I write in the FROM stage?

i got this picture, it said docker container does not need os,but use the host os,now docker build always need an os
[image]

Comment: Docker shares *the kernel* with the host OS. There's more to an operating system than just a kernel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create docker image without source image (OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100576/create-docker-image-without-source-image-os)

Answer (score 16):

The containers on a host share the (host's) kernel but each container must provide (the subset of) the OS that it needs.

In Windows, there's a 1:1 mapping of kernel:OS but, with Linux, the kernel is bundled into various OSs: Debian, Ubuntu, Alpine, SuSE, CoreOS etc.

The `FROM` statement often references an operating system but it need not and it is often not necessary (nor a good idea) to bundle an operating system in a container. The container should only include what it needs.

The NGINX image uses Debian ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a973c221f6cedede4dab3ab36d18240c4d3e3d74/mainline/buster/Dockerfile)).

In some cases, the container process has no dependencies beyond the kernel. In these cases, a special `FROM: scratch` may be used that adds nothing else. It's an empty image ([link](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch)).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think the meaning of docker is deploy but not the compile, so it always need an OS, am i right?

Comment: Nope, The docker is platform similar to VM can be used all purpose like Compile, deploy what not.

Answer (score 11):

**No** its not like that. To create any docker image using DockerFile, You need to start with a **base docker image**. That base docker image can be anything, Like an empty image as well, In the docker file in your example the **FROM** section says ubuntu, it means its assuming ubuntu as the base image. Its not always needed to have an OS as base image.

Follow this link - https://linuxhint.com/create_docker_image_from_scratch/
This will clear your doubts related to base image.

Answer (score 5):

now i got answer

the From stage import the software but not the OS with kernel

it just provide a platform for your application,the ubuntu,debian,centos you write in FROM stage is just a software,the true kernel does not have relationship with them.

so if your application can run dependent ,it must like hello-world ,just a binary-package,dont rely on any other library. but mostly you need an OS,because they have the library you need.

Comment: does that mean if I install, say tensorflow, that tensorflow will directly get to interact with the main OS (macOs in my case) instead of the container's OS (ubuntu)?

Because if that is the case, I can install tensorflow version that works with Mac's GPU.

Answer (score 3):

No, the `FROM` stage is not providing the operating system to the image. The kernel is always provided by the host system where you are running the container. The `FROM` stage provides the initial file system i.e., files, directories, pre-installed softwares etc for the new image. You can also start `FROM scratch` which is like a blank slate.

Answer (score 0):

The FROM line need NOT necessarily point to any other OS:
It can be any other container or it could be FROM SCRATCH.

Containers in host share kernel so you can think as it is master process utilizing host kernel.

Generally people see HTTPD, NGINX etc. are utilizing Debian as container OS, since this Debian OS is very thin and serves the purpose of isolation and runs as independent server.
Even you can create a HTTPD, NGINX without using any OS and name with your own version :-)